# Why does my application terminate if user closes separate window?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, windowlistener

I have a simple GUI program that creates a new window (which contains a `JTable`) at some point in time. If the user closes the `JTable`, the main application closes as well. How do I prevent this? Would it have something to do with how it handles the window closing, or should I give it it's own thread, or what?

Comment: My guess is that your main thread already finished, causing the entire program to shut down when the window is closed. Can you post the (relevant parts of) your code?

Comment: the user can't close the JTable, but is closing the window or JFrame. JTable is a component only

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set one of these close operation for your `JFrame`: `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` or `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.
You are using `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) is a link to the JavaDoc method you can use.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working, still quits entire application :(

Comment: Never mind, was putting it in the wrong place. Everything works, thank you so much!